# Evolution equations for normalized mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from 260th page of  G. Huisken's [Flow by mean curvature of convex surfaces into spheres](http://diyhpl.us/~bryan/papers2/frey/levelsets/Huisken%20G.,%20Flow%20by%20mean%20curvature%20of%20convex%20surfaces%20nto%20spheres.pdf).

First, I think it should be 
$$\widetilde h_{ij}(x,\widetilde t)=\psi(\widetilde t) h_{ij}(x,\widetilde t).$$

Second, I don't know how to differentiate (14). Consider locally, then 
$$
\int_{\widetilde U_t} d\widetilde\mu=\int_{\widetilde F(U,t)}\sqrt {\widetilde g(x,t)} dS=\int_{\psi(t) F(U,t)} \psi(t)\sqrt{g(x,t)}  dS
$$
Then I am not sure how to proceed.

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one way of all, and there should be some way is more easy. In fact , the area of $M_t$ is 
$$
\int_U \sqrt {\widetilde g} dx =\int _U\psi\sqrt g dx
$$
Then 
$$
0=\partial_t \int _U\psi\sqrt g dx =\psi '\int\sqrt g+ \psi\int -\frac{1}{n}H^2\sqrt g
$$
So
$$
\frac{\psi'}{\psi}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{\int H^2\sqrt g}{\int\sqrt g}
$$